# How to implement persisting related (cascading) objects via JDBC

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

I have related objects consisting of parent entities such as Organisation.java which has object-typed  child attributes as @OneToMany lists like activities (i.e. List activitiyList) (Activiy.java  has its own object-typed attributes.

It is very easy to use JPA persistence to do CRUD operations of these objects on a database, but my current requirement forbids me to use JPA, and implement the same functionality using only-JDBC - which I'm not sure how to implement.

How could the same functionality be implemented via JDBC when both parent and child objects are  created for the first time (i.e. with all of the objects having null IDs)?

Comment: What did you try? Normally you would just iterate over your `Collection`s and save them via your self-implemented JDBC-methods. (e.g. in your Data Access Object)

Comment: What database? and can you use spring, or must you use pure JDBC only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a foreign key relationship between Organisation and Activity, you must create the parent first, then the child rows with the parent id.

You can do this with spring, [here's](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/68129-problem-with-parent-child-tables-foreign-key-constraints-transactional-inserts) an old post, but the principals remain the same.

To implement manually, your database must provide a mechanism by which to generate primary keys for a given table without having to create a row first. Oracle supports sequence.nextVal, so your database should support something similar.

I'm pseudo-coding this, you can fill in the blanks:

```
try{
   connection.setAutoCommit(false)

   //get organisation id first
   String nextOrgIdSql = "select orgSeq.nextval from someVirtualTable" //depends on database
   ResultSet orgIdRs = statement.executeQuery( nextOrgIdSql)
   int orgId = -1
   if( orgIdRs.next())    
      orgId = orgIdRs.getInt(1)

   //create organisation first
   String orgSql = 
      "Insert into ORGANISATION (ORGID, ...) values ("+ orgId + ",...)"

   //create activities
   for( Activity activity : organisation.getActivityList()){
      String nextActvIdSql = "select activitySeq.nextval from someVirtualTable"
      ResultSet actvIdRs = statement.executeQuery( nextActvIdSql)
      int actvId = -1
      if( actIdRs.next())    
         actvId = actvIdRs.getInt(1)

      statement.execute(
        "Insert INTO ACTIVITY (ACTVID, ORGID) values ("+actvId+","+orgId+")"
   }

   connection.commit()

}catch(SQLException e){
  connection.rollback()
}
```